# What are the limitations of using AWS appsync api(GraphQL) through Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I just want to avoid use of custom/manual resolvers in appsync completely. So I'm using Amplify to  setup GraphQL appsync API in my app. I'm doing all the stuffs  by changing `schema.graphql` and `amplify push`.

**I have 2 questions :**

**1.** What are the limitations and what problems I'm going to face in future?

**2.** Can graphql subscriptions get update when app is not running(like user should be notified)?

Answer (score 0):

1. tons of business logic will be exposed on the client side code.
2. I think for push notifications you would still have to go via external integrations like FCM/APNS. Multiple integration options are available in SNS

Answer (score 0):

Just to preamble these answers, the fact that you use an amplify generated graphQL and resolvers doesn't stop you from later including [custom resolvers and pipeline functions](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/custom-business-logic/#override-amplify-generated-resolvers) - it's just that you need to learn quite a bit about where to include them in the backend file structure of amplify.

> *1. What are the limitations and what problems I'm going to face in future?*

This depends on how well your applications use-case matches the graphQL schema design and if your application is relatively self-contained. Amplify becomes more complex when your application needs to talk to other back-end systems, you'll need to start using [DynamoDB triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) to notify other state machines/event bridge/SNS or similar services.

As mentioned none of these problems are crippling, you can deal with them later but it will be a step up in the AWS knowledge required to implement them.

For small high-volume/availability apps Amplify and DynamoDB as-it-comes is great. If your application matures into many micro-services and sites then you'll need to learn quite a bit more AWS to make them play together well. Amplify does determine your DynamoDB on a table per object basis and you'll probably be stuck with (paying for) that. Think hard about if you ever might want to go to a different optimised data source (RDS or single dynamo table) to reduce the number of queries required to fulfil your graphQL requests.

> *2. Can graphql subscriptions get update when app is not running(like user should be notified)?*

No. Anurag mentions SNS which would be a good option to out-app notify users, best to blend subscriptions and another service.